# R Shiny application creates a table containing checkboxes

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I want to create a table containing checkboxes in R Shiny application.
However, I want to make it impossible to edit the part where there is no check box on the table.

I tried the rhandsontable package, but I could not create a table containing both editable and non-editable parts.

How can I create a table that contains both editable checkboxes and non-editable parts in the R Shiny application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
  library(magrittr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(rhandsontable)

  DF = data.frame(integer = 1:10,
            numeric = rnorm(10),
            logical = rep(TRUE, 10), 
            character = LETTERS[1:10],
            factor = factor(letters[1:10], levels = letters[10:1], 
                            ordered = TRUE),
            factor_allow = factor(letters[1:10], levels = letters[10:1], 
                                  ordered = TRUE),
            date = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 rhandsontable(DF, width = 600, height = 300) %>%
 hot_col("factor_allow", allowInvalid = TRUE)
```

Comment: I want to know if it is impossible to create an editable part and an uneditable part of the checkbox.

I knew it after posting, but I seem to be able to specify a non-editable part with hot_cell.

Comment: Well you can answer your own question for someone that have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could specify an uneditable part with the following command.
I think Shiny will work as well.

```
library(rhandsontable)
df <- data.frame(logical1 = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE), logical2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA))
rhandsontable(df) %>% hot_cell(3, 2, readOnly = TRUE)
```